# Why is TinyMCE displaying HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, tinymce

I am trying to integrate [TinyMCE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react) with React in frontend and django(DRF) in the backend.

When I save data from TinyMCE, it save the data along with HTML tags and same data is displaying back with the HTML tags like

```
<p>test</p> <div>Test inside div</div>
```

What would be the best possible way to display data without HTML tags and in proper web page format?

Here is TinyMCE element settings

```
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';


 handleSubmit = e => {

        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {

                this.props.blogCreate(this.state.title, this.state.short_title, this.state.content);

                console.log(this.props.res)
            }


        });
    };




    handleEditorChange = (e) => {

        this.setState({
            content: e.target.getContent({ format: 'text' })
        })

    }

                        <Editor
                            apiKey="************************"
                            //initialValue="<p>Blog Content</p>"
                            //cloudChannel='stableDefault'

                            init={{
                                selector: 'textarea',
                                plugins: ['advlist autolink autosave lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
                                    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
                                    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table  directionality',
                                    'emoticons template paste  textpattern imagetools codesample toc help'],
                                toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
                                toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample help',
                                image_advtab: true,
                                file_browser_callback_types: 'image',
                                valid_elements: 'p,br,div,Row,Col,a[title|target|href],strong,em,ul,ol,li,--[*]',

                                branding: false,
                                height: 400,
                                contextmenu: 'formats | link image',
                                forced_root_block: false,
                            }}

                            name='content'
                            onChange={this.handleEditorChange}

                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

Editor.activeEditor.selection.getContent({ format: 'text' });
```

or

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' });
```

Comment: based on your suggestions I have updated my question. Now its is saving data without html tags, but now my concern is how do I display data in its original format, like h1 tag in bigger font, p in smaller font. as because now it is removing all the required html tags . Can you please look into this?

Comment: actually i am trying to save data with or without html tags (I don't know which one will be better) but my only concern is when user fill the content with the help of "Source Code" in editor , all the html tags like p, span, div , h1, h2 should work as a normal html element but not to display the tags itself.

Comment: you cant do that. You need to store the html content inside your db. If you affair of security concern consider apply render trusted html

Answer (score 0):

to  display data in its original format HTML, you need to add this when you get the text from the database inside a div: 
 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.content}}